# Eliminar paquete NuGet y todas sus dependencias de una vez?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, nuget

Es posible eliminar un paquete Nuget y todas sus dependencias de un tirón en `Xamarin`?

Por ejemplo: Tengo un proyecto en `Xamarin.Android C#` en donde necesito eliminar varios paquetes, uno de ellos es `AndroidX`, pero para iniciar tienen como 100 complementos y luego de eso tenemos que A depende de B; B depende de C; C depende de D, etc. Lo que involucra `Firebase.Auth` lo cual es bastante extenso tambien.

Es una labor muy tardada si lo hacemos desde el `Administrador de Paquetes NuGet`.

Hay algún truco que puedan compartir para aligerar este trabajo?